# Thomas Cole's Political Commentary

Tags: united-states

I'm studying Thomas Cole's "[Course of Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Course_of_Empire_(paintings))" paintings, but despite what is implied through the artwork itself, I cannot find any references from Cole himself regarding his political motivations.

For example, [this article](https://www.libertarianism.org/columns/art-ideas-thomas-coles-course-empire) essentially implies that he "harbored deep suspicions of democratic virtue."  I can understand why that conclusion is drawn, but cannot find actual source material where Cole makes these claims.

And if he never did, is it theoretically ok from a historical perspective to make assumptions such as that, based on his artwork alone and the frame of reference to the era he was active?

Comment: Are you looking for this? **Essay on American Scenery** by Thomas Cole - [_American Monthly Magazine 1 (January 1836)_](https://www.csun.edu/~ta3584/Cole.htm)

Comment: Interesting, though doesn't contain overt references to political leaning, despite some comments adoring freedom.  I'm more or less looking for any mention Cole had towards politics, either contemporary or generalized - for instance, this page - http://www.explorethomascole.org/coles_circle - states that Cole "bitterly opposed.. [the] expansionist, utilitarian, and democratic policies... of Jacksonian America."  I cannot find a source from Cole himself substantiating any of these claimed political persuasions, however, besides what is implied through his paintings.